# Significant drop in the age of having first child after the Flood

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mabul

There is a significant drop in the age of having first child after the Flood. Shem begot Arpachshad already two years after the Flood, when he was 100. Arpachshad begot his first child when only 35. And so forth. Is this drop related to the commandment that Hashem gave to Noach, to procreate and fill the Earth? If so, this commandment was given much earlier to Adam, and it did not lead to the same effect.
Any references to some commentary? I did not find any *mefaresh* that would relate to this.

Comment: I have seen that it is connected with the drop in lifespan. Consider the percentage of life that passed.

Comment: The command to Adam was "פְּרוּ וּרְבוּ וּמִלְאוּ אֶת-הָאָרֶץ, וְכִבְשֻׁהָ", and Noach was told "פְּרוּ וּרְבוּ, וּמִלְאוּ אֶת-הָאָרֶץ", without "וְכִבְשֻׁהָ", so possibly Adam and his children waited until their prime, so their children would be stronger, while Noach's children had children earlier, since their task was to fill the earth, but not to conquer it.

Comment: Do we know with certainty that the children that were mentioned in the genealogy were the firstborn? Maybe those children who were mentioned were part of the "critical path" that the Torah wanted to mention at that time.

Comment: Agreeing with @sabbahillel's concept (would like to see support, if you have "seen it". It's also possible that biological structure of humans at the time may have had women become pregnant at a later age. Another explanation could be simply that the Torah may be listing the most "important" child as if it were the first born. It's possible that there were many other children that were born much earlier.

Comment: @Salmononius2 That is possible, but then it would seem that after the Flood it was the oldest children who are listed (based on the relatively young age of the father) while before the Flood it was children who were born later.

Comment: @DanielEvalUlay Even after the flood it is possible that the men listed were not the firstborn but were the most relevant.  For example, do we know that the child begot be Arpachshad at the age of 35 was his first? People gan procreate at half that age.